# I have one issue with my ListActivity menu issue

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I make application where I want to implement ListActivity menu. I used [this](http://www.thenewboston.org) tutorial. 
I have one issue.

If I run my application and run ListActivity, emulator display error:

```
12-27 12:42:34.387: E/AndroidRuntime(756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 12:42:34.387: E/AndroidRuntime(756): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tomaszsudol.simplyfun/com.tomaszsudol.simplyfun.PolishWebsites}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-27 12:42:34.387: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
```

My code PolishWebsites.java:

```
public class PolishWebsites extends ListActivity {

    String[] classes = {"Demotywatory", "Kwejk", "Bebzol" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pl_websites);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(PolishWebsites.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try {
        Class myClass = Class.forName("com.tomaszsudol." + cheese);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(PolishWebsites.this, myClass);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


}
```

My pl_websites.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I found where I made mistake. I added unnecessarily this line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.pl_websites);
```

After taking the tutorial exercises, I should see if the script working and how. 
I added above line because I wanted display ListView in layout. This was unnecessarily.

---

Thanks for answer.

If I set

```
<ListView 
     android:id="@+id/list" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ListView>
```

Eclipse display error as below.

```
12-27 12:42:34.387: E/AndroidRuntime(756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 12:42:34.387: E/AndroidRuntime(756): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tomaszsudol.simplyfun/com.tomaszsudol.simplyfun.PolishWebsites}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-27 12:42:34.387: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
```

Comment: Use   android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: Inside xml use this  android:id="@+id/list" instead of  android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"

Comment: You have to set id like,android:id="@+id/R.id.list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ListView` design to this.

```
<ListView 
       android:id="@+id/list" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 0):

**android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"** this will assigned as **android.R.id.list** not **"list"**

You need to set id like this way

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

or you can do this way also

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ListView  as

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </ListView>
```